# Access multidimensional array value

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, multidimensional-array

Trying to get the value inside a multidimensional array to populate another array in single values. I will then use that array to query the WordPress database.

Currently my code outputs and array like so:

```
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 56
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 24
    )
```

)

I need it to be array( '56,'24 ). Is this possible?

My code so far is:

```
$data = unserialize( $_POST['ordered-items'] );

foreach( $data as $product => $order ) {


        $products[] = array( $product );

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to:

```
foreach( $data as $product => $order ) $products []= $product;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that, i simply put couple of them

This is using **array_walk_recursive**

```
    $return = array();
    array_walk_recursive($data, function($a) use (&$return) { $return[] = $a; });
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($return);
    echo '</pre>';
```

This is using **array_merge**

```
$result = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $data);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```